# How to generate LCOV report based on Jasmine's SpecRunner.html?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, lcov

We are using Jasmine for our JavaScript unit tests. We have a `SpecRunner.html` file to run the tests. Does there exist a tool to which I can pass the path to `SpecRunner.html` and the path to the directory of JavaScript (not the specs) files and it would generate a LCOV report. For example, something like this:

```
phantomjs jasmine_lcov.js SpecRunner.html WebContent/js
```

Answer (score 11):

I agree with @zaabalonso that [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/) is the correct choice.  Since you want LCOV reports, you'll also need the [karma-coverage](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage) plugin and presuming you want to run headless in CI you'll probably want the [karma-phantomjs-launcher](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-phantomjs-launcher).  Running through Grunt is optional as you can always run karma directly from the command line with karma-cli (`npm install -g karma-cli`).

A basic setup (with requireJS) looks something like this:

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-jasmine-node": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.10.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "karma": "^0.12.32",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-requirejs": "^0.2.2",
    "requirejs": "^2.1.17"
  }
}
```

**karma.conf.js** (Notice the `preprocessors` and `coverageReporter` sections

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
  basePath: '.',
  frameworks: ['jasmine', 'requirejs'],
  files: [{
        pattern: 'src/**/*.js',
        included: false
      }, {
        pattern: 'spec/**/*.js',
        included: false
      },
      "test-main.js"],

  preprocessors: {
    'src/**/*.js': ['coverage']
  },

  reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],

  coverageReporter: {
    // specify a common output directory
    dir: 'build/reports/coverage',
    reporters: [
      { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'report-lcov' },
      { type: 'lcovonly', subdir: '.', file: 'report-lcovonly.txt' }
    ]
  },

  browsers: ['PhantomJS']
  });
};
```

**test-main.js**

```
var allTestFiles = [];
var TEST_REGEXP = /^\/base\/spec\/\S*(spec|test)\.js$/i;

var pathToModule = function (path) {
    return path.replace(/^\/base\//, '').replace(/\.js$/, '');
};

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function (file) {
    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        // Normalize paths to RequireJS module names.
        allTestFiles.push(pathToModule(file));
    }
});

require.config({
    // Karma serves files under /base, which is the basePath from your config file
    baseUrl: '/base/',
    enforceDefine: true,
    xhtml: false,
    waitSeconds: 30,

    // dynamically load all test files
    deps: allTestFiles,
    callback: window.__karma__.start
});
```

**Gruntfile.js** (Optional if you want to use Grunt)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        options: {
          singleRun: true
        }
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['karma:unit']);
};
```

You can run the tests command line with `karma start`.  That will launch the karma server and run the tests once.  It will keep the server up and will re-run the tests anytime you modify your source or test sources.  If you want to run the test only once (in CI perhaps) you simply run `karma start --single-run`.

Comment: This is a good solution, but i actually have a NODE env to test, so i can use a browser for run the test, so i need to do it without Karma, do you know any way to do it?

Comment: Helped me setting up my LCOV report output in just a couple of minutes. A super good answer. Since more than 3 years have passed since it was given: using PhantomJS now is rather risky as the main contributor of the project left the ship and effectively March 2018 that project has come to a halt. I will go with ChromeHeadless instead.

Answer (score 3):

[Chutzpah](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah) will also do this.  It is focused on Windows platform however, so that may or may not work for you.  Here is the full command line options [documentation](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/command-line-options), but your command might be something like this:

```
chutzpah.console.exe SpecRunner.html /coverage /lcov coverage.dat
```

If you need to fine tune things like coverage excludes or references, etc, you can use json config files places in the area where the tests are as described [here](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File).  There is no need to specify location of your Javascript code under test on command line as that is automatically detected by references in SpecRunner.html.

I have found Chutzpah to be very slick and easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

We are using [Karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/grunt-karma) over grunt the config looks like that:

```
  options = {
        karma: {
            unit: {
                options: {
                    files: ['test/unit/specs/*.js'],
                    reporters: ['progress', 'coverage'],
                    preprocessors: {
                        'src/js/*.js': ['coverage']
                    },
                    coverageReporter: {
                        type : 'html',
                        dir : 'build/coverage/'
                    },
                    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
                    singleRun: true
                }
            }
        }
}
```

you don't specify the

> SpecRunner.js

but you can specify *.js for all your spec files.

you can run it with

> grunt karma

that will generate your report similar to the one you showed.